# Are there any "design patterns" in C?

Tags: c, design-patterns

I know that design patterns is generally something that's connected to OO programming, but do you have some pattern you often use when you program C?

I'm not interested in simple translations of the classical OO patterns and please don't mention Duff's device. ;-)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

My favorite is the "Patterns in C" series by [Adam Tornhill](http://www.adamtornhill.com):

- [First-Class ADT](http://adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%201.pdf)
- [State](http://adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%202,%20STATE.pdf)
- [Strategy](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%203,%20STRATEGY.pdf)
- [Observer](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%204,%20OBSERVER.pdf)
- [Reactor](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%205,%20REACTOR.pdf)

Also: I always think of `goto` as a great poor man's tool for the decorator pattern.

**Update**: I'd highly recommend using **Rust** ([rust-lang.org](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/)) or **Zig** ([ziglang.org](https://ziglang.org/)) rather than C except where you are required to use c. Rust has all of the benefits of c, including speed and binary library compatibility with c, but the compiler handles much of the complexity to ensure that the code is memory safe and does not contain data races. It's also portable, has a standard library for common tasks, and much easier to program with for various design patterns.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `goto` has to do with decorators?

Comment: This is a great little series by Adam Tornhill (was Petersen). His [complete book](https://leanpub.com/patternsinc) is available. This small set of patterns will take you a long way in C.

Comment: Rust is not quite C equivalent. It's different enough to not be equivalent. For instance, you can call C code from almost any language but have to turn off name mangling in Rust. Also rust admittedly prevents valid programs to retain theoretical guarantees with the borrow checker. I also like rust but thought this deserved a counter argument.

Comment: @BotsFab Fair enough. I added Zig. :)

Answer (score 14):

Design Patterns could be viewed as missing language features. The Introduction of [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) states:

> The choice of programming language is
>   important because it influences one's
>   point of view. Our patterns assume
>   Smalltalk/C++-level language features,
>   and that choice determines what can
>   and cannot be implemented easily. *If
>   we assumed procedural languages, we
>   might have included design patterns
>   called "Inheritance," "Encapsulation,"
>   and "Polymorphism."* Similarly, some of
>   our patterns are supported directly by
>   the less common object-oriented
>   languages. CLOS has multi-methods, for
>   example, which lessen the need for a
>   pattern such as Visitor. (*italics mine*)

The sentence in italics is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 9):

Polymorphism via callbacks, e.g. the standard library's `qsort` function.  All it needs is a way to compare two elements, and it can sort an array of them.

You can be much more sophisticated than this by using sets of functions (vtables) to represent the pertinent properties of a type so that a generic routine can process it usefully.  For example, the read, write, etc. calls on an open file, or network port.

Comment: I like the use of callbacks. You can create a general data structure traversing function that executes a callback function on each element.

Answer (score 9):

From the top of my head

- [Using gotos for error handling](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+Goto-Chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources)
- [Objects implemented with structs and function pointers](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/include/linux/device.h#L89)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are. Lazy initialization, singleton, object pool, object state etc. are easily implemented in pure C.

Example (lazy initialization)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo
{
    int payload;
};

int calculate_payload()
{
    printf("%s\n", "Performing lengthy initialization...");
    return 42;
}

struct foo *get_default_foo()
{
    static int foo_calculated = 0;
    static struct foo default_foo;
    if (!foo_calculated) /* assuming single-threaded access */
    {
        foo_calculated = 1;
        default_foo.payload = calculate_payload();
    }
    return &default_foo;
}

int main()
{
    struct foo *foo1, *foo2;

    printf("%s\n", "Starting the program");

    foo1 = get_default_foo();
    printf("%d\n", foo1->payload);

    foo2 = get_default_foo();
    printf("%d\n", foo2->payload);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, they probably are, but how would you typically implement one of these patterns in C?

Comment: The better point is that you **should not** implement bad design patterns (like singletons, aka global variables) in C, or any language for that matter.

Comment: @R.: I really don't think that singleton is a bad pattern per se. It _can_ be useful and productive in certain cases, _can_ be harmful for the code quality in certain cases. But the developer **must** know the advantages and disadvantages of the design patters, and use them judiciously.

Answer (score 3):

Design Patterns often model things that are just one level from what an existing environment offers. If you take C with its standard library as the environment an eminent design pattern is Object Orientation.

Answer (score 3):

Virtual File System is perfect example for learning the Design Pattern.